# Alternative CDI injection not working as expected

Tags: java, cdi, jboss7.x

I have two classes that implement an interface. The one is annotated as `@Default` and `@Named`. The other is annotated as `@Alternative`

```
@Default
@Named
public class ListService implements IListService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething()
       print("default");
    }
}

@Alternative
public class ListServiceMock extends BaseServiceMock implements IListService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething()
       print("mock");
    }

}
```

The injection happens like this:

```
public class SomeNavigator extends AbstractNavigator {

    private IListService listService;

    @Inject
    public SomeNavigator(IListService listService) {
        this.listService = listService;
    }

    public void doNavigate() {
       this.listService.doSomething(); // Always prints "mock"
    }
}
```

My `beans.xml` file is in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml and the project is built and packaged by Maven as a war file and deployed to **JBoss EAP 6.3.3.GA** (in a Docker container)

I believe that the alternative bean `ListServiceMock` will **only** be injected if I include it in the `beans.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="all" version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>service.alternative.ListServiceMock</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

However regardless of if that section is in the `beans.xml` or not the alternative bean is always used.

Is there a reason why it seems the `beans.xml` file is ignored in this case and the alternative bean is **always** selected for injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be related to the XML namespaces in the `beans.xml` file. I swthced to these namespaces and it's working now.

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
```